# Select minimal count of grouping by result without window functions

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, h2

As always, want to do with one sql request. Have a table of send attempts:

```
ID  TIMESTAMP            TASK_ID
1   2019-01-30 15:29:38  1
2   2019-01-30 15:29:39  1
3   2019-01-30 15:29:40  2
4   2019-01-30 15:29:41  3
```

Task table:

```
ID  EMAIL            
1   boxOne@test.com
2   boxOne@test.com
3   boxTwo@test.com
```

Purpose is to get task ids for unique emails that has minimal count of attempts (in our case is 2 and 3). Problem number one is that i want make some tests using H2 that not supports window functions. Problem two is that several tasks can have same email.

Tried this :

```
SELECT TASK.id, TASK.EMAIL, count(att.TASK_ID)
FROM TASK
JOIN ATTEMPTS on TASK.id = ATTEMPTS.TASK_ID
GROUP BY ATTEMPTS.TASK_ID
```

and have such result:

```
TASK.id  EMAIL            count(TASK.id)
1        boxOne@test.com  2
2        boxOne@test.com  1
3        boxTwo@test.com  1
```

but i need minimal count for each unique email like this:

```
TASK.id  EMAIL            count(TASK.id)
2        boxOne@test.com  1
3        boxTwo@test.com  1
```

min(count(TASK.id)) didn't work for me result is always zero.

Can this be done without window functions or i should accept temp result and process it in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a correlated subquery, `HAVING` and `ALL`

```
SELECT t.id, t.email, count(a.task_ID) cnt
FROM task t
JOIN attempts a on t.id = a.task_ID
GROUP BY t.id, t.email
HAVING count(a.task_ID) <= ALL
(
    SELECT count(a.task_ID)
    FROM task t2
    JOIN attempts a on t2.id = a.task_ID
    WHERE t2.email = t.email
    GROUP BY t2.id
)
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bee00c0c524a76837fe647fdae1bc95c)

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using correlated subquery

```
select distinct t1.* from 
(
SELECT TASK.id, TASK.EMAIL, count(att.TASK_ID) cnt
FROM TASK
JOIN ATTEMPTS on TASK.id = ATTEMPTS.TASK_ID
group by TASK.id, TASK.EMAIL
) t1 where t1.cnt= (select min(cnt) from 
                       (SELECT TASK.id, TASK.EMAIL, count(att.TASK_ID) cnt
                       FROM TASK
                       JOIN ATTEMPTS on TASK.id = ATTEMPTS.TASK_ID
                        group by TASK.id, TASK.EMAIL
                       ) t2 where t2.EMAIL=t1.EMAIL)
```

Comment: I think you are missing `GROUP BY` behind `JOIN`s

Comment: Yep, error: Column "TASK.ID" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement: